# Is there a way to dissolve glue?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions

**Background**: I have a journal from my childhood. I applied glue (uhu brand. [this one](http://www.uhu.com/uploads/tx_uhuproducts/46015_Detail_01.png)) to the papers almost 10 years ago.

**Q**: Is there a way to dissolve the glue and make the pages readable?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Can you post some more information on the glue, such as manufacturer details etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try different solvents on a spot that does not have writing, to see if it removes the glue, and on glue with non-critical writing, to see if it *removes or smears the writing as well as the glue*.

Since it described as a [clear synthetic resin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UHU), you might try the following sequence, from milder solvent to stronger:

1. Comparatively mild non-polar organic solvents, such as paint thinner or kerosene. If that does not dissolve the glue, try
2. Some Polar solvents such as acetone, methyl ethyl ketone or nail-polish remover. If that does not remove the glue, try
3. PVC pipe solvent ([tetrahydrofuran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrofuran)).

**N.B. All solvents listed are flammable, and some are fairly toxic. Use them in *small quantities*, closing the containers after getting a bit out, to prevent flash-back of flames, and use in well-ventilated areas.**