# Need to dissolve glue placed intentionally in a lock

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Someone intentionally sabotaged the lock on the front door of my house by putting glue inside it apparently, I have no idea what type of glue it is. Is there any chemical substance I can use to dissolve the glue instead of having to replace the entire lock?

Also, would heating the lock work?

I took a look at [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/is-there-a-way-to-dissolve-glue), the heating option wasn't possible since they're talking about paper, but I was wondering if it'll work before trying any of the chemicals mentioned.

Please consider that I don't have much experience in Chemistry while answering, thank you for your time.

Comment: If it's superglue, it should be dissolved pretty easily by acetone (i.e. nail polish remover), though it'll take a while. Superglue is, in my experience, the weapon of choice for vandals since it's cheap and hardens quickly, so that's a good starting point. On the other end of the spectrum, if they used casting polymers, you might just be out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

To paraphrase the link you mentioned,

Without knowing the specific glue, you should try different solvents to see if it dissolves the glue:

- Start with a mild, non-polar solvent like paint thinner.
- If that doesn't work, try a polar solvent like acetone.
- If that doesn't work, try [tetrahydrofuran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrofuran) (PVC pipe solvent)

All of these solvents are flammable and pretty nasty if you get them on you. To minimise risk, use small quantities at a time, minimise the time that the lid is off the container. The fumes shouldn't be too much of a problem if you're outside, but still take care.